# is it possible to set focus for a TextBox in its TextChangeEvent

Tags: c#, textchanged

(Visual Studio 2019 winform)I want to have my Textbox on Focus when the label associated to the Textbox is visible , here is my code:

```
private void jTextBox9_TextChangeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char c in jTextBox9.TextValue.ToLower())
            if (!eng.Contains(c))
            {
                label23.Text = "This Field has to be in English";
                label23.Visible = true;
                jTextBox9.Focus();

            }

            else
            {

                label23.Visible = false;

            }

    }
```

the only problem in this code is that the `.Focus()` and `.Select()` method doesn't work in the `TextChangeEvent`, is there any solution to this? Thanks for the help

Comment: If the text is changing, then the textbox has the focus, because someone is entering text. Also, your logic is wrong, because is makes the label visible or invisible repeatedly for each character.  Instead you should check whether there is at least one disallowed character and after the loop set the visiblity of the label.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes do you have the code for that please?

Comment: a) it should work but b) don't set the focus in a loop! @Olivier: Changing the text in code will also trigger the event

Comment: @TaW, yes but I don't know whether it is a good idea to set the focus while the text is begin edited. I added a check before setting the focus now.

Comment: _I don't know whether it is a good idea..._ Same here :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the text is changing, then the textbox has the focus, because someone is entering text.

Also, your logic is wrong, because is makes the label visible or invisible repeatedly for each character. Instead you should check whether there is at least one disallowed character and after the loop set the visibility of the label.

```
private void jTextBox9_TextChangeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool containsDisallowedChar = false;
    foreach (char c in jTextBox9.TextValue.ToLower()) {
        if (!eng.Contains(c)) {
            containsDisallowedChar = true;
            break; // Exit the loop.
        }
    }
    if (containsDisallowedChar) {
        label23.Text = "This Field has to be in English";
        label23.Visible = true;
        if (!jTextBox9.Focused) { // In case text is changed in code.
            jTextBox9.Focus();
        }
    } else {
        label23.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code, the jTextBox9.focus();  still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: TextChanged also fires without the textbox having the focus.  Triggered by code assigning the Text property.  The "still doesn't work" scenario is this happening before the form's Shown event has fired.

Comment: This would mean that winforms is setting the initial focus after this code did run. The OP uses a `TextValue` property. Not sure which kind of control he is using.